# How do I get the bottom border width of a html Element in c++(using msdn api's/property)?

Tags: c++, border, atl

I have a html div element which has a "solid" property when I check the get_borderBottomStyle(). I would like to get the value of the border in pixel. All the other sides(top,left and right) give a "none" property with their respective styles. Is it possible to get the border value in this scenario? If yes, please let me know how I can get it.

I have tried using get_borderBottomWidth() which gives a BSTR index and my required value. Not sure how I can extract/utilise this.

**Update**:
It seems there is a get_borderWidth() which returns the border's type of thickness(medium, thin or thick) if they have a style "none". In my case it returns medium medium 1 px.(These are for top, left/right and bottom respectively). It's of type VARIANT. Is there a way to get only the value from this?

Comment: What particular library? MFC, ATL, CLI Forms?

Comment: visual c++ libraries. ATL

Answer (score 0):

```
pcurrentStyle->get_borderBottomWidth(&vtborderBottomWidth); //This gets the bstr address and the border width with px
lborderBottom =vtborderBottomWidth.bstrVal;// This gets the border width with px
char* borderBottom = NULL;
borderBottom = convertBSTRToCharPtr(lborderBottom);//  method which converts bstr value to char pointer
long clborderBottom = atol(borderBottom);// converts the value to long.
```